# Autocomplete [jquery] no muestra datos

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

tengo el siguiente problema, tengo dos campos para autocompletar (nombre de grupo y numero del mismo) y la parte logica funciona correctamente pero no me muestra las coincidencias, como se puede observar los valores aparecen en la consola, pero no en la pagina.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo en la logica (PHP -Laravel 5.2)

```
public function groupNumber(){
      $queries = Group::where(function($query){
        $query->where('number','like','%'.Input::get('term').'%');
      })->take(5)->get();
      foreach ($queries as $query) {
        $results[$query->id] = $query->number;
      }
      return response()->json(['item' =>$results]);
    }
```

Este es el codigo jquery

```
$('#txtGroupNumber').on('keypress',function(){
    $('#txtGroupNumber').autocomplete({
      source: '../autocomplete/groupNumber',
      minLength:3,
      select: function(event,ui){
        $('#txtGroupNumber').val(ui.item.value);
      }
    });
    $('#txtGroupNumber').data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul,item){
      var $li = $('');
      $li.attr('data-value',item.value);
      $li.append(""+item[1]);
      console.log(item);
      return $li.appendTo(ul);
    }
  });
```

Comment: en la variable $li = $('<li style="margin-bottom:.5em;">');

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tu backend está devolviendo un array asociativo (que javascript interpreta como un objeto) en vez de un array plano (que js interpreta como un array).

Como el autocomplete espera un array, tienes que asegurarte de entregar un array plano desde el backend. Específicamente, si estás usando el autocomplete de jquery-ui, el backend debiera entregar un array de arrays asociativos compuestos de `id` y `value`.

```
public function groupNumber(){
  $queries = Group::where(function($query){
    $query->where('number','like','%'.Input::get('term').'%');
  })->take(5)->get();
  $results=[];
  foreach ($queries as $query) {
    $results[] = ['id'=>$query->id, 'value'=>$query->number];
  }
  return response()->json($results);
}
```

Tienes otro problema en tu frontend porque estás reinstanciando el autocomplete en cada keypress, cuando el widget de autocomplete de por sí escucha los cambios en el contenido del input.

Esto significa que debiera bastar poniendo simplemente

```
$('#txtGroupNumber').autocomplete({
  source: '../autocomplete/groupNumber',
  minLength:3,
  select: function(event,ui){
    //$('#txtGroupNumber').val(ui.item.value);
    console.log(ui.item);
  }
});
```

Y el parámetro `select` en realidad no necesitas declararlo a menos que el cambio en tu selector gatille cambios en otro input, pero a simple vista no es el caso.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba hacerlo así:

- Modifica tu función `groupNumber` para que devuelva un arreglo de objetos con propiedades, por ejemplo, con `id` y `number`.

  ```
  public function groupNumber(){
    $queries = Group::where(function($query){
      $query->where('number','like','%'.Input::get('term').'%');
    })->take(5)->get();

    $results = [];
    foreach ($queries as $query) {
      $results[] = array(
        'id'=> $query->id,
        'number'=> $query->number
      );
    }
    return response()->json($results);
  }
  ```
- Modifica tu código javascript, para que el `autocomplete` se inicialice de entrada y que en `source` utilice un función. Dentro de esta función ejecutamos un 'ajax' para buscar los posibles resultados para el valor ingresado (`term`). En el `success` del `ajax`, hay que formatear los datos a [un formato que el `autocomplete` entienda](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source).

  ```
  $("#txtGroupNumber").autocomplete({
    minLength:3,
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url: "../autocomplete/groupNumber",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
          term: request.term
        },
        success: function(data) {
          // Al recibir los datos devueltos, los formateamos
          // de modo que el Autocomplete entienda cual es el valor (`value`)
          // y cual es el texto (`label`) para cada una de las opciones
          var formatted = [];
          $.each(data, function(index, info) {
            formatted.push({
              label: info.number,
              value: info.id
            );
          });

          // Le pasamos los datos formateados al Autocomplete
          response(formatted);
        });
      }
    });
  });
  ```